# how do I set custom currency in ssrs reporting services

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I would like to add a currency symbol to the data that is displayed in my ssrs report . Since I do not have null values I would like to 
do a check for not null then add the symbol via formatting this is what I have tried so far . I am using vs 2008.

```
=IsNothing(Fields!Cost.Value)<>"True" = Brazil, R$ CStr(Format(Fields!Cost.Value, #,###,###,###.00))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Following Code.
Hope this is the solution you are searching for.

```
=IIF(isNothing(Sum(Fields!value.Value)),"","R$"+Cstr(Format(Sum(Fields!value.Value),"#,###,###,###.00")))
```